# Count all tables on page, grab their id's and run through array

Tags: jquery, arrays, count

I have a page with a number of tables generated by php, mysql. And some jquery I would like to run on each table.

Im thinking the best way to do it would be to create an array of the table ids and run the jquery in a foreach.

Thing is I have no idea how to do this so if anyone has any idea on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

EDIT/// This is the code I would like to run on each table

```
    $("#frontshade:radio").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children(":checkbox").attr('checked', false);
  $(this)
   .closest('table') // find the parent row
       .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in that row
           .attr('disabled','disabled') // disable them
           .removeClass('disabled'); //Toggle class
    $("#frontshade :checkbox").hide();
    $("#frontshade .cbox").hide();

    $(this).parent().children(":checkbox").show();
    $(this).parent().children(".cbox").show();
    });
    $("#frontshade :checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this)
   .closest('tr') // find the parent row
     .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in that row
       .toggleDisabled()
       .toggleClass('disabled','slow') // enable them
   .end() // go back to the row
   .siblings() // get its siblings
       .find(":input[type='text']") // find text elements in those rows
           .attr('disabled','disabled')
           .removeClass('disabled'); // disable them
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through the tables and grab their ids, as well as perform any other operation you would want:

```
var table_ids = new Array();
$('table')
    .each(function(e){
        table_ids[] = $(this).attr('id');
        //do other stuff with each table
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I run this on each table I thought I would be able to figure it out but im struggling see edit

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table').each(function() {
  // do stuff with table
});
```

Or do you mean MySQL tables?

Comment: Thanks for that, Im still struggling to implement it I have included the code I would like to execute in the original post.

Comment: Can you add your code. Including your HTML code. @ http://jsfiddle.net/ . And tell me exactly what you want to do. And I will fix it for you!

Comment: All i need is to know how to replace '#frontshade' with the unique id for the current table in the loop

$("#frontshade :radio").click(function() {};
$("#frontshade :checkbox").hide();
$("#frontshade .cbox").hide();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703091/run-jquery-on-each-table simplified question and code

Answer (score 1):

You know, the following code would achieve the same:

```
jQuery('table').each(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

More details in [the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started,

```
$('table').each(function(index, table){
    table.find('td').each(function(index, el){
        el.doSomething();
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Im still struggling to implement it I have included the code I would like to execute in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tables to have the same script, you could also add a class to the table and say:

```
$('table.doIt').each(function ()
{
    // your code here
}
```

I think getting all ID's is a bit awkward, because just adding a class to the tables you want to run the jQuery on seems a bit easier. It costs less effort in JS and just one extra class addition in you PHP.