# Run jquery on each table

Tags: jquery, arrays

Below I have some jQuery that runs through each table with the classname = sizetable

I would like to execute this:

```
$("#frontshade :radio").click(function() {});
```

But I'm not sure how to replace the `#frontshade` with the id from the array

```
  var table_ids = new Array();
  $('.sizetable')
  .each(function(e){
    table_ids[] = $(this).attr('id');
  // JQUERY TO EXECUTE ON EACH TABLE        

  $("#frontshade :radio").click(function() {};

  //

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `$(this).find('input:radio')`.
The [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find) finds all descendants that match a selector.

Note that [`input:radio` is faster than `:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).
As  the documentation states,

> `$(':radio')` is equivalent to
>   `$('[type=radio]')`. As with other
>   pseudo-class selectors (those that
>   begin with a ":") it is recommended to
>   precede it with a tag name or some
>   other selector; otherwise, the
>   universal selector ("*") is implied.
>   In other words, the bare `$(':radio')`
>   is equivalent to `$('*:radio')`, so
>   `$('input:radio')` should be used
>   instead.

Comment: why am i getting a syntax error on this line?

        table_ids[] = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: @Tommy: Because it's invalid syntax.  You probably want to write `tableIds.push($(this).attr('id'))`.

Comment: Thanks I have it working exept one thing $(this).find(".cbox").hide(); doesnt hide the class i obviously cant use find. Again thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's selectors are simple javascript Strings. So you could easily append other string to it:

```
$( "#" + $(this).attr('id') + " :radio").click(function() {};
```

That'll do the work ;)